# How to hide or ignore System.err outputs in IntelliJ console

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have some Java code running in the IntelliJ IDE, and I am using third party libraries that print a lot of messages (using System.err) as part of their main functionality. As a result the output I see in the IntelliJ terminal is quite messy.

I want to ask the community if there is a way of hide the messages that come from System.err in the IntelliJ terminal so only the output from System.out is shown.

Update: The question is focused on how to modify the IntelliJ IDE to not show the errors. Without modifying the code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install the [GrepConsole Plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125) and try to create a regex pattern that filters out the things you don't want to see.

Answer (score 2):

There are several libraries that first try to find out the logging mechanism your application is using. If they do not find anything, they fall back to [Java's own logging mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html). Java logging prints out log messages on System.err by default.

So you basically have these options:

1. Redirect System.err to your own custom PrintStream, where you can do all sorts of filtering.
2. Provide a reasonable configuration for the Java logging mechanism.
3. Use a logging library - like log4j, logback, or whatever - and do not forget to configure the third-party library in the logging configuration.

Comment: Thanks but the question would be how to modify the IntelliJ configuration. (See update)